# Analyzing an Image's histogram

Tags: image-processing, histogram, gpuimage

I have a photo editing app that is built around Brad Larson's amazing
GPUImage framework.
I need a way to analyze an image's histogram so i can return it's range.
Meaning the real range of "activity".
I need this to improve a tool i have in the app that controls the RGB composite curve.

Is there a way to analyze or retrieve hard numbers from the histogram filter in GPUImage ? any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As I document in [the Readme.md](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for the GPUImageHistogramFilter:

> The output of this filter is a 3-pixel-high, 256-pixel-wide image with
>   the center (vertical) pixels containing pixels that correspond to the
>   frequency at which various color values occurred. Each color value
>   occupies one of the 256 width positions, from 0 on the left to 255 on
>   the right. This histogram can be generated for individual color
>   channels (kGPUImageHistogramRed, kGPUImageHistogramGreen,
>   kGPUImageHistogramBlue), the luminance of the image
>   (kGPUImageHistogramLuminance), or for all three color channels at once
>   (kGPUImageHistogramRGB).

To get the numerical values for the histogram, have the GPUImageHistogramFilter output to a GPUImageRawDataOutput and grab bytes from that. The result will be a 256x3 (width, height) array of 0-255 values indicating the intensity at each color component. You can ignore the first and last rows, as the values are only present in the center row.

From there, you can analyze the histogram obtained by this operation.